# find the first match of a regex in a file, and print it

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a collection of words on one side, and a file on the other side. I need their intersection. i.e. the words that do appear at least once in the file.

I am able to extract the matching lines with

```
sed -rn 's/(word1|word2|blablabla|wordn)/\1/p' myfile.txt
```

but I cannot go forward.

Thank-you for helping, Olivier

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39044) thread should provide some insight

Answer (score 1):

If I got you, you just need to pipe `sed` results to `uniq`:

```
sed -rn 's/.*(word1|word2|blablabla|wordn).*/\1/p' myfile.txt | uniq
```

Also you need to match the whole line in sed in order to get just the desired words as output. That's why I've placed `.*` in front and at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps' [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) may work here?

```
grep -o -E 'word1|word2|word3' file.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: Works! Thank-you guys for helping. I did not knew this -u option. Much more straightforward that sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using grep and sort:

```
grep -o 'word1\|word2\|word3' myfile.txt | sort -u
```

The `-o` switch makes grep only output the matching string not the complete line. `sort -u` sorts the matching words and removes duplicates.

Comment: Many thanks, it did not worked whithout the -E option, but you showed me the right track.